# Wordpress single post display in archive

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, popup, custom-post-type

I have custom Wordpress posts. Currently, each post that is displayed on the list is downloaded with Ajax and displayed in a popup. I don't have a single post page.

I wish that when someone comes from the url to single post `/customPost/namepost` to redirect them to the archive page, keeping the single post url. Then I will get the id using `url_to_postid()` and display a specific post in the popup.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can add post id to each post for example in data attribute.
Example for archive.php

```
while(have_posts())
    the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    <div class="" data-postId=<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
        // post content
    </div>

endwhile
```

Then if user click on specific post, you can get post id from data attr by using JS/JQ.
https://api.jquery.com/data/

Content in popup you can display by using REST API.

Comment: I have already done that.  Now I wonder how to handle post display when someone comes in from the source link.  I would like it to be displayed in the popup too, but on the archive page, not on the single post page.

Comment: You can show specific post by using REST API on everywhere place.